# How to filter firebase data based on timestamp using startAt & endAt

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to filter firebase data using startAt and/or endAt.
My data is structured as below.

```
{
  "notes" : {
    "-LOs0Ikx4ydM5RatREM1" : {
      "data" : {
        "dueDate" : 1561629600000,
        "description" : "Korewa nan desuka?!",
        "createdAt" : 1539611900000,
        "title" : "First "
      },
      "members" : {
        "author" : "1212121212121212121212121212"
      }
    },
    "-LOs0Ikx4ydM5RatREM2" : {
      "data" : {
        "dueDate" : 4004870448000,
        "description": "Test"
        "createdAt" : 1539611900000,
        "title" : "Second"
      },
      "members" : {
        "author" : "1212121212121212121212121212"
      }
    },
    "-LhBt9msLFKqUQ-koI9W" : {
      "data" : {
        "dueDate" : 1564653600000,
        "description" : "abc",
        "createdAt" : 1560363158279,
        "title" : "August 1"
      },
      "members" : {
        "author" : "3434343434343434343434343434"
      }
    },
    "-LhBtKdDrQv9eKuYdfCi" : {
      "data" : {
        "dueDate" : 1564653600000,
        "description" : "abcdef",
        "createdAt" : 1560363158279,
        "title" : "August 2"
      },
      "members" : {
        "author" : "3434343434343434343434343434"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I wish is to fetch all "notes" where dueDate has passed.

```
const now = moment().valueOf() //Eg. 1561629500000
database.ref('notes/')
  .orderByChild("dueDate")
  .endAt(now)
  .once("value", (snapshot) => {
    console.log('Process expired notes')
    snapshot.forEach( (data) => {
      const obj = data.val()
      console.log('Date comparison:', (now >= obj.data.alertDate))
      ...
```

The code above does not work, it returns all the objects from the example JSON. The console.log logs "False" for three out of four returned objects.

I could do a comparison and only process the objects that meets my criteria, but that would defeat the purpose.

I have indexed the database on ["notes\data\alertDate"].

What am I missing? I must have misinterpreted the documentation somehow. :)

Comment: Can you replace the database structure with a snippet of the actual JSON from your database? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thank you Frank for the prompt reply! :) I Have updated with JSON snippet. All of the objects in the snippet are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dueDate` property is nested under `data`, so you need to address is as `data/dueDate`:

```
database.ref('notes')
  .orderByChild("data/dueDate")
```

You might want to include both a `startAt()` and `endAt()` clause, with just a reasonable value for `startAt()` and the specific value you're already using for `endAt()`.

Comment: Of course! Many thanks! :D Thanbks for the tip - I will also include startAt().